# Gridview sorted header css not loading

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView that has it's columns loaded from codebehind.  The header CSS class I specified in the aspx page, but it wasn't loading for these columns.  So I added: GridView1.HeaderRow.CssClass = "HeaderStyle" in the codebehind after binding and then it loaded.  I can't figure out how to do this for the sorted column style though.

Here's the codebehind.  Any idea what I need to enter to style the sorted column and where it should be added? Can I specify "SortedAscendingHeaderStyle" and "SortedDescendingHeaderStyle" for the sorted column anywhere?

```
Sub Page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        CreateGridColumns()
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub

Public Property SortExpression As String
    Get
        If ViewState("SortExpression") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("SortExpression") = "LastName ASC"
        End If
        Return ViewState("SortExpression").ToString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("SortExpression") = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CreateGridColumns()
    Dim curLastName As New BoundField
    curLastName.HeaderText = "Last Name"
    curLastName.DataField = "LastName"
    curLastName.SortExpression = "LastName"

    GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, curLastName)


    Dim curFirstName As New BoundField
    curFirstName.HeaderText = "First Name"
    curFirstName.DataField = "FirstName"
    curFirstName.SortExpression = "FirstName"

    GridView1.Columns.Insert(1, curFirstName)

End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Try
        Dim tblData = New DataTable
        Using sqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString())
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeList ORDER BY {0}"
            Dim sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            sqlCmd.CommandText = String.Format(sql, Me.SortExpression)
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon
            Using objAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                objAdapter.Fill(tblData)
            End Using
        End Using
        GridView1.DataSource = tblData
        GridView1.DataBind()

        GridView1.HeaderRow.CssClass = "HeaderStyle"

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' TODO: log error '
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView1.PageIndexChanging
    Me.GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    BindGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Sorting
    Dim currentSortColumn, currentSortDirection As String
    currentSortColumn = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(0)
    currentSortDirection = Me.SortExpression.Split(" "c)(1)
    If e.SortExpression.Equals(currentSortColumn) Then
        ' switch sort direction '
        Select Case currentSortDirection.ToUpper
            Case "ASC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " DESC"
            Case "DESC"
                Me.SortExpression = currentSortColumn & " ASC"
        End Select
    Else
        Me.SortExpression = e.SortExpression & " ASC"
    End If
    BindGrid()

End Sub
```

Here's the GridView mark up:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." AllowPaging="True" 
 CssClass="GridViewStyle" GridLines="None" Width="100%">

 <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Dept" SortExpression="Dept" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="EmplID"
        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="EmployeeProfile.aspx?EmplID={0}"
        DataTextField="EmplID"
        DataTextFormatString= "<img src='Images/icons/document-search-result.png' alt='View'/> <u>View</u>" >
        <ControlStyle CssClass="titleLinksB" />
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
    </asp:HyperLinkField>

    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
        <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>

</asp:GridView>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I've seen code that uses SortedAscendingHeaderStyle so I tried GridView1.SortedAscendingHeaderStyle.CssClass = "sortasc" in BindGrind() but that's not working for me.

Comment: @Zach Green Yes I'm using 4.0.  Is there something I should change because of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f you use the built in sorting for a GridView linked to a data source, you can define them in markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4">
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle CssClass="SortedAscendingCellStyle" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedAscendingHeaderStyle" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle CssClass="SortedDescendingCellStyle" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="SortedDescendingHeaderStyle " />
</asp:GridView>
```

Since you are implementing your own sorting and data binding, you will also need to set the sorted column style yourself in the RowDataBound event.

```
    protected void gdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
        string sortColumn, sortDirection;
        sortColumn = this.SortExpression.Split(' ')[0];
        sortDirection = this.SortExpression.Split(' ')[1];

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
            int cellIndex = -1;
            foreach (DataControlField field in gridView.Columns) {
                if (field.SortExpression == sortColumn) {
                    cellIndex = gridView.Columns.IndexOf(field);
                }
            }

            if (cellIndex > -1) {
                //  this is a header row, set the sort style
                e.Row.Cells[cellIndex].CssClass = sortDirection == "ASC" ? "sortasc" : "sortdesc";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I actually do have them in markup.  It works fine if the GridView is being populated by an SQLDataSource, but when I have the columns created in codebehind it doesn't get the sorted class.  I also have the HeaderStyle added in markup, and the codebehind-created columns get that class fine, just not the sorted header class. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: @Cineno28, yeah, since you are implementing your own data binding and sorting, you cannot use the markup option. I have updated my answer with an option when implementing your own sorting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I added your code (after converting it to VB).  After sorting I didn't see the style applied to the actual sorted column, but checking the html I see that it's being applied to a blank header column from a link column that I add in the actual markup as opposed to codebehind.  Do you know why it's going to this column instead of the actual sorted column? I just added the GridView markup above if it helps.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Cineno28, yeah, it is doing that because the gridView.SortExpression is empty, and it hits the hyperlink column that has an empty sortexpression, and so it marks that column to be changed. To fix this, instead of comparing to gridView.SortExpression and gridView.SortDirection, you should compare to Me.SortExpression. I have updated the answer to handle that (you'll still need to convert).

Comment: Thank you so much! I made the change and it's working now.  I was really stumped on this, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Cineno28, no problem. Be sure to clean up your SQL code to either use the 'using' statement or try/finally blocks so that you don't leave the DB connection open on an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
    protected void grid_RowSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        string sortDirection = GetSortDirection(sortExpression);
        //.. Fill Grid & Sort Grid
        SetHeaderSortCss((GridView)sender, sortExpression, sortDirection, "defaultCss"); 
    }

    private void SetHeaderSortCss(GridView grid, string columnName, string direction, string defaultCss)
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grid.Columns[i].SortExpression.ToLower().Trim() == columnName.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                grid.Columns[i].HeaderStyle.CssClass = "sort"+direction; //Set sorted Css
            }
            else
            {
                grid.Columns[i].HeaderStyle.CssClass = defaultCss; //Clear Others Css
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string SortExpression)
    {
        if (ViewState[SortExpression] == null)
            ViewState[SortExpression] = "Desc";
        else
            ViewState[SortExpression] = ViewState[SortExpression].ToString() == "Desc" ? "Asc" : "Desc";

        return ViewState[SortExpression].ToString();
    }
```